# Laravel $request->all() is throwing 'Cannot access empty property' message

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a weird problem trying to validate the fields on a form with laravel. According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation), in order to do so I need to do  this:

```
Validator::make($this->$request->all(), $this->$validationRules)
```

But currently I'm getting this annoying message '**Cannot access empty property**'.

I have tracked the error to this expression `$this->$request->all()`, as it seems that all() property is not defined... Weird thing cause if I do, for instance something like `$this->request->input('name')` I'll get the value sent by the input with name='name' correctly on my controller .

Why is that property seems to be empty? Is there anything I'm missing to create my validations properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
$this->request
```

Instead of this:

```
$this->$request
```

Also, check if you're injecting `Request` object first:

```
public function method(Request $request)
{
    $this->request = $request;
```

Or you could just use [`request()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-request) global helper:

```
request()->all();
```

Comment: Hi @Alexey, thanks for your reply. None of yor solutions did work for me but I created a new request class using `php artisan make:request ` command and then I passed that Request  as my parameter and now is working just fine.